# How to send message to alertController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I am learning Objective-C,and I want to create a tableView.When i touch on a table,an alert view is presented.The alert view will show a name , a description and two textFields which can input the new name and description.How can i change the name and the description by clicking the "Ok" button.here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    Coder *coder = _allCoder[indexPath.row];

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Jack" message:@"Jack is a coder" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder =@"name"; }];
    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"description";}];
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];


    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
        UITextField *name = alertController.textFields.firstObject;
        coder.name = name.text;
        UITextField *desc = alertController.textFields.lastObject;
        coder.desc = desc.text;
    }];
    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:okAction];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: It is not possible , because `Ok` closes the alert view controller.

Comment: create custom alert box

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan it means i can't use AlertViewController to change data?

Comment: Sure you can change data - but outside of its elements by clicking on Ok. It's useless to change text inside textfield that will hide very soon.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the data in the table based in the data that was entered into the the alert? What you have looks ok. You need to reload the tableview row if you want to see the updated data in your table